# JMeter - in different geographical location

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, loadrunner, neoload

I need some advise. I always worked on prim setup and had my JMeters in the same data center as application server to be tested. Now we got a cloud set up and I can ask for JMeters in different geographical locations in cloud to mimic real production behavior of the load. So is that what I should do? Will the response times of the transactions have network disturbances in them or it will be in fact like production? ...in on-prem testing when we have JMeters in the same data center as test application servers we totally eliminate network issues from the response times!!

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 different types of the [performance metrics for the websites](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420665-Performance-Metrics-for-Websites):

1. Perceived System Performance
2. Perceived User Experience

**Perceived System Performance** won't be impacted by geo-distributed JMeter setup, the backend doesn't really care where the requests are originating from and how much time it takes the request/response to travel over the wire back and forth. In fact the system will receive less load comparing to the same test scenario running in the same network.

**Perceived User Experience** will be different and you will experience larger response times as it takes some time for the packet to physically travel around the globe and pass through all routers/switches on its way towards the system under test and back.

In terms of [JMeter Glossary](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html)

1. [Latency](https://web.dev/ttfb/) will be higher
2. Delta between latency and elapsed time will be higher